# How to create tables with space as borders between columns

Tags: tables, formatting, columns

I can separate columns in my tables with lines by adding a `|` at the beginning as in `\begin{tabular}{ |l|l| }`.

How do I separate columns with space such that it's aligned as done in the following table?

[image]

Solution that worked for me:

```
 \begin{longtable}[c]{ll@{\hspace{30pt}}ll}
 \multicolumn{2}{}{}
 \hline
 MNIST &  & CIFAR-10  & \\

 \hline
 \endfirsthead
 \hline
 \endlastfoot

 Conv.ReLU & 3 x 3 x 32 & Conv.ReLU & 3 x 3 x 96\\
 Conv.ReLU & 3 x 3 x 32 & like this\\
 Max Pooling & 2 x 2 & like this\\
 Conv.ReLU & 3 x 3 x 64 & like this\\
 Conv.ReLU & 3 x 3 x 64 & like this\\
 Max Pooling & 2 x 2 & like this\\
 Dense.ReLU & 200 & like this\\
 Dense.ReLU & 200 & like this\\
 Softmax & 10 & like this\\

 \end{longtable}
```

Comment: `ll` instead of `|l|l|` then.

Comment: Note how the table has 4 columns, and the space between columns 2,3 is greater than the space between columns 1,2 and 3,4. How can I do that?

Comment: @AnnaVopureta It depends on how the table columns are defined, please add a minimal but complete example of your code which creates this table.

Comment: `{l@{\quad}l@{\qquad}l@{\quad}l}`.

Comment: @AnnaVopureta If you want to customize the width of the columns, `p{3cm}p{4cm}p{2in}` then. You only have to get rid of the `|`. To get rid of the space between columns, use `@{}` as the accepted answer stated.

Comment: By the way, you don't have to add the solution to your question. People will find that solution in the accepted answer. If you have another solution, you should answer your own question instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can adjust the spacing beween individual columns to your liking using `@{<length>}` as shown in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll@{\hspace{20pt}}ll}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```